# Which branch is used when I create a new branch from an issue on Gitlab? Can I choose the source branch?

Tags: gitlab

I'm working on *GitLab Community Edition 8.15.3*.

When I go to *my project* --> `Issues` --> select an issue (let's say which is named "*Fix UI problem on IE8*") --> *`New branch`*.
It creates a new branch named `41-fix-ui-problem-on-ie8` without asking me to select **the original/source branch**.

My 2 questions are:

- What's the default original branch used by Gitlab when I create a new branch from an issue?
- Is there a way to "*force or activate an option on Gitlab*" to give me the choice to select the source branch when I create a new branch from an issue?

Comment: what IDE you are using?

Comment: @Suraj I'm using Eclipse as an IDE but I create branches directly from Gitlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the "New Branch" button in an issue, the branch is created off of the project's default branch. Normally that would be the `master` branch, but you can set the project's default branch in the project settings.

###### UPDATE

GitLab has added the ability to specify the source branch when creating a branch or merge request in an issue. You have to click the dropdown arrow on the "Create merge request" button, and then you'll see these options:

[image: Create Merge Request Dropdown]

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for:

"you can set the project's default branch in the project settings"

and 

"there is no way to choose the source branch when creating a branch from an issue". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

your answers:

> What's the default original branch used by Gitlab when I create a new
>   branch from an issue?

When you create a new branch, by default the current branch you are in is your source branch. you can change it according your requirements.

> Is there a way to "force or activate an option on Gitlab" to give me
>   the choice to select the source branch when I create a new branch from
>   an issue?

yes you can always change your source branch. if you are creating a new branch github, first select the branch you want to make  source, and then create new branch it will show like this: [image]

other wise you can use git command line Interface.. its very powerful then GUI. 
see the [git command line](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-The-Command-Line).

Answer (score 1):

Given the current version of Gitlab, you can now specify the branch source when creating the branch and merge request from an existing issue:

[image]